Mimic CSV File In Testing
I have a LWC that I use to upload a file.  The file is basically a census file.  The Javascript puts the value of the file in a variable named fileContents using the below code which is then passed to apex to do some checking.  I am struggling on how to recreate the fileContents in a test class so I can pass it to the apex.  Here is a snippet of what gets created in fileContents using the javascript.

"DOB,Gender,Zip,Type,Product\r\n2/8/1967,M,8077,S,Prod 4\r\n5/4/1982,F,8077,F,Prod 3..."

The first column is the headers and then the data.
Any help about how I can recreate this varaible in apex?  Thank you!!
// check and process file that is being uploaded
  uploadHelper() {
    this.file = this.filesUploaded[0];
    if (this.file.size > this.MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
        window.console.log('File Size is to long');
        return ;
    }
    this.showLoadingSpinner = true;
    this.fileReader= new FileReader();
    this.fileReader.onloadend = (() => {
        this.fileContents = this.fileReader.result;
        this.processFile();
    });
    this.fileReader.readAsText(this.file);
  }


Have you considered placing a test CSV in a Static Resource and accessing it via  StaticResource in Apex?

One way (if you are only talking about the CSV content):
String[] lines = new String[] {};

lines.add(String.join(new String[] {
    'DOB',
    'Gender',
    'Zip',
    'Type',
    'Product'
}, ','));
lines.add(String.join(new String[] {
    '2/8/1967',
    'M',
    '8077',
    'S',
    'Prod 4'
}, ','));

...

String fileContents = String.join(lines, '\r\n');

